# Помещение элементов массива в список html.

Tags: html, jquery, массивы, list

В список(в тэг `<a>`) должны по очереди выводится элементы массива но если что то и выводиться то только    последний элемент. Пробовал сделать через for(in) получилось тоже самое.

```js
$(function() {
  var contacts = ['Jenny Hess', 'Elliot Fu', 'Stevie Feliciano', 'Christian', 'Matt'];
  $("div").append('<ul>');
  $("ul").append('<span>');

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    $("ul").append('<li>');
    $("li a").html(contacts[i]);
  }
  $("li").append('<a>');

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapperDropdown"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    $("ul").append('<li><a>' + contacts[i] + '</a></li>');
  }
```